# Process Builder not reevaluating a key formula field

Tags: process-builder, workflowrule

I have quite a quandary which I have searched for a few hours on the forums with no luck.

**Process Builder Rules:**

- "Recursion - Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction" = YES
- "Start the process: when a record is created or edited"
- Activates on the Child Object (Utility Account)
- Rules: Activates when the Child Object is set to ACTIVE and the field NumActiveUtilityAccounts on the Parent Object = 1

**Object Types:**

Parent Object: Opportunity,

Child Object (custom): Utility Account

**Important Fields:**

On the Child Object, there is a field called "ACTIVE" (checkbox)

On the Parent Object, there is a roll-up field which counts how many Children have been marked ACTIVE (0, 1, 2, etc. ). This field is called NumActiveUtilityAccounts

**ISSUE I AM HAVING:** 
Scenario: There are no active utility accounts (NumActiveUtilityAccounts = 0). I am creating a utility account (child object) under the parent object, and when I create it, it is marked as ACTIVE. Although the process builder should fire since it is ACTIVE and now the NumActiveUtilityAccounts = 1, it does not because of some issue with the formulaic / rollup field NumActiveUtilityAccounts.

Sorry if this seems quite complicated, but maybe someone can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your process builder on the child object is failing to execute because the field 'NumActiveUtilityAccounts' on the parent object Opportunity is not yet updated and still has value 0 in the database.

Please review the salesforce order of execution in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

I would recommend exploring options on parent record to drive your business logic.